# how to divide an input file into different output files based on information of the first column at input in R?

Tags: r

I want to make saparated output files based on unique values in input file. so the input looks like:

```
input.txt:
1 23 
1 22
1 2
1 45
1 33
2 22
2 1
2 1
3 22
3 45
3 44
```

I want to have separated output files base on uniq values in first column of input. so:

out1.txt:

```
1 23 
1 22
1 2
1 45
1 33
```

out2.txt

```
 2 22
 2 1
 2 1
```

out3.txt

```
3 22
3 45
3 44
```

Any suggestion? my real input is a huge file

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried  awk command  in shell . but it did work well.

Comment: you could use `grep` in shell to read all lines that starts with one specific number

Comment: What about `grep  "^1 .*" input.txt | out1.txt ...`?

Comment: @HubertL This gives error: bash: out1.txt: command not found..

Comment: Sorry : `grep "^1 .*" input.txt > out1.txt`

Comment: @HubertL but there are too many values . I can not just do this for each value one by one. how can I make a loop to make all out put by one run?

Comment: Sooo, this is not an R question then.  Please change the language tag.

Comment: @RichardScriven If you know how to do it in R then let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this R, I will provide an R answer.  Here is a base R method first, with a *data.table* method down below.

```
## read the data into R
df <- read.table("input.txt")
## split the data frame by the first column
s <- split(df, df[[1L]])
## write each table in 's' to file 'out*.txt'
invisible(
    Map(write.table, x = s, file = sprintf("out%s.txt", seq_along(s)))
)
```

Now you should have three new files "out1.txt", "out2.txt", and "out3.txt" based on your example data.

Alternatively, we can speed this up with the *data.table* package.

```
library(data.table)
## read the data
dt <- fread("input.txt")
## write each chunk of 'dt' to file 'out*.txt' by group
dt[, write.table(cbind(V1 = .GRP, .SD), sprintf("out%s.txt", .BY)), by = V1]
```

Obviously this makes some assumptions about column names, but it is easy to change those values accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not R... but since you are supposed to have a very big file, this simple `bash` scrip won't load the whole thing into memory

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   grep "^$i .*" input.txt > out$i.txt
done
```